# Define open graph image sizes for facebook

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I search through the internet to find proper solution for this problem. But I didn't found one.

To share a web page in facebook I used open graph as follows same as mention in facebook developer site.

```html
    <meta name="description" content="Description is here" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/11.png" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Business Intelligence, Big Data, Data driven" />
        <meta name="developer" content="companyName">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Image size of this the png file is 796x417 px

This code properly show in correct ratio of 1.91:1 in facebook post sharing in facebook wall and messenger applications.

But in facebook inbox it show in 1:1 ratio as follows(last message). This only show cropped image, therefore some characters are missing

[image]

Is there any way(open graph) to view that image in specific ratio for facebook inbox and facebook wall share.

As an example can I use two different images for share link in wall post with 1.91:1 ratio and another image with 1:1 ratio for inbox.

Comment: please mention the reason if you are down voting

Answer (score 4):

You should follow closely the OpenGraph specs in defining image/s and their properties : http://ogp.me/#array . So defined a preferred image and then define the height and with, then define another as a fallback and so on. Give it a try and let us know what you achieved. Maybe you can control the aspect ratio by giving the images some base heights/widths.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/11.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="796" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="417" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/12.png" />
```

Comment: this is not working, i have tried many times different method it appears only one image and that is the first image if is available,
what i want is to share different images on different apps with same link